# CSS Image overlapping on navbar

Tags: html, css, image, tags

Image is transparent when scrolled from my fixed navbar. I tried using:

```css
image{ 
  z-index: -1;
  position:relative;
  position:absolute;
}
```

but the image still shows on the navbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eird.png

Comment: We're not likely to bother guessing what your CSS, or HTML, might be. Could you please share a (relevant) sample of your "*[mcve]*" code with us?

Answer (score 0):

try putting a background on your navbar. try using

```
.navbar{
position:fixed;
background-color:white;
}
```